# Trouble using PDFkit with Meteor

Tags: pdf, meteor, pdfkit

I am using `PDFkit` with `Meteor` and am getting an error

> object has no method 'writeSync'

Can anyone tell me which package contains this method? Am I missing something?

My packages include:

- `meteorhacks:async`
- `meteorhacks:npm`
- `npm-container`
- `cfs:filesystem`
- `cfs:standard-packages`
- `pascoual:pdfkit`

The documentation contains `meteor` add `pascoual:pdfkit` and suggests that it would add 2 fibered methods `writeSync` and `outputSync`, but they are not found.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The PDFKit package itself has a `writeSync` method defined on `PDFDocument`. Are you using the pdf generation code on the server or the client? It'll work only on your server side code.

Comment: Would the method get added when the package is added to my Meteor app?  Yes, I am using it in a js file located inside a server folder so it is running on the server side. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

m using PDFKit in the server side using 2 alternatives:

1. Rounting: lib/router.js

   Router.route('/createPDF/:_ParamId', function() {
       var paramId = this.params._ParamId;
       if (!paramId) return;

   ```
   var doc = new PDFDocument({
       size: 'A4',
       margins: {
           top: 50,
           bottom: 0,
           left: 50,
           right: 50,
       }
   });

   doc.image(process.env.PWD + '/public/sample1.jpg', 0, 30);

   this.response.writeHead(200, {
       'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
       'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=somename.pdf'
   });
   this.response.end(doc.outputSync());}, { where: 'server' });
   ```

And, calling from client using:

```
Router.go('/createPDF/' + someParamId);
```

2. Calling Meteor method

   Meteor.call('createPDF', paramId);

And changing the PDF building method

```
Meteor.methods({
    createPDF: function(paramId) {


        if (!paramId) return;

        var doc = new PDFDocument({
            size: 'A4',
            margins: {
                top: 50,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 50,
                right: 50,
            }
        });

        doc.image(process.env.PWD + '/public/img/sample1.jpg', 0, 30);

        ....

        doc.writeSync(process.env.PWD + '/public//pdf/' + pdfName + '.pdf');
    }
});
```

I have only one trouble, that doesn't work in my blabla.meteor.com test app, the server cannot found the images using doc.image(...)

Comment: Solved:

I'd used that code

    `var basePath = process.cwd() + '/../web.browser/app/';
    doc.image(basePath + 'img/layers/sample1.jpg', 0, 30);`

And works perfecly